# How to remove Glow of Button on Mouse hover in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, mousehover

I am using a simple button in WPF.
I have put an image for the button on background.
My problem is, when i move mouse pointer to button it get a default glow and override the image given as background.

```
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Name="Play" BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Focusable="False" Width="45" Height="45" Click="Play_Click"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6,10,6">
            <Button.Background >
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/play.png"  />
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Foreground>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/play.png"  />
            </Button.Foreground>
        </Button>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's defined in Button's [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx). You should create your own.

for example like this.

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
           <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can apply this style to your Button. and set Background to that image of yours.

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Name="Play" BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Focusable="False" Width="45" Height="45" Click="Play_Click"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6,10,6">
        <Button.Background >
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/play.png"  />
        </Button.Background>
</Button>
```